# How to detect my position in an ng-repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to output a list of `<li>` elements using `ng-repeat="obj in links"`, where `links` is an array of objects with `href` and `text` properties:

```
$scope.links = [
    { href: '/asdf', text: 'asdf'},
    { href: '/qwer', text: 'qwer'},
    /* etc. */
    { href: '/zxcv', text: 'zxcv'}
];
```

But I want the `ng-repeat` loop to change what it does when it reaches a certain object in that array. Specifically, I want the loop to create hyperlinks for every object until `obj.href==location.path()` -- and after that, I just want to write out the text inside a `<span>`.

---

Currently, I'm solving this by creating both links and spans each time in the loop:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in links" ng-class="{active: location.path()==obj.href}">
        <a ng-href="{{obj.href}}">{{obj.text}}</a>
        <span>{{obj.text}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FGMPT9fj7zKsix12uyH8?p=preview)

I then use CSS to hide all hyperlinks after the `active` class and hide all spans before it. But I don't want to just hide the links after the condition matches -- I want them to be completely removed from the DOM.

Comment: Why not use `ngIf` directive?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to. I can see how to use `ng-if` when `location.path()==obj.href`, but how to use it *only* on every loop iteration after that?

Comment: Are you sure your `location.path()` is working? Or you have scope property `location` which then you assigned `$location` service to it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure -- the `ng-class` condition works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two things you must do.

1. Find the index of the active element
2. Only show links up to the active index, and after that only show spans

What about this:

In your controller

```
$scope.lastIndex = 0;
$scope.$watch('links', function(newVal, oldVal){
    for(var i=0; i< newVal.length; i++){
        if (newVal[i].href == location.path()){
            $scope.lastIndex = i
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In your HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in links">
        <a ng-if="$index <= {{lastIndex}}" ng-href="{{obj.href}}">{{obj.text}}</a>
        <span ng-if="$index > {{lastIndex}}">{{obj.text}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Used a modified version of this -- instead of `$watch` I use `.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', ...)` -- and it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Very good initiative. I used $watch because I thought maybe your links variable might change on the same page and you'd want to always update the content. But if the variable never changes it's better not to use $watch which is a "dirty watcher"

Answer (score 0):

please see that example http://jsbin.com/cifef/1/edit

for your solution you need to replace `$scope.location.href` by `location.path()`

```
$scope.isLast = false;
  $scope.getValue = function(obj)
  {

    if( obj.href==$location.path() || $scope.isLast )
      {
        $scope.isLast = true;
        obj.isLast = true;

      }


  };
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in links" ng-class="{active: location.href==obj.href}" ng-init="getValue(obj)">

        <a ng-href="{{obj.href}}" ng-hide="obj.isLast">{{obj.text}}</a>
        <span ng-show="obj.isLast">{{obj.text}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```